# Error with IsEmptyOrNull

Tags: asp.net

This code:

```
if (!String.IsEmptyOrNull(Request.Form["Bef_Days"]))
{
   ...
}
```

Is giving this error:

> 'string' does not contain a definition for 'IsEmptyOrNull'

I am new at ASP.NET so might I be missing some namespace?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you got it backwards. It's IsNullOrEmpty.

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.Form["Bef_Days"]))
{
   ...
}
```

Comment: Well this is embarrassing. I guess I should not start working without coffee. Thank you. Will upvote all the answers and pick yours as solution since I think you were the first.

Answer (score 2):

It is `string.IsNullOrEmpty` not `IsEmptyOrNull`

So your code should be :

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.Form["Bef_Days"]))
{
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Its `String.IsNullOrEmpty` and not `String.IsEmptyOrNull`